# Using Yargs inside Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, yargs

I'm working with yargs to pass arguments in a gulp command. I am having troubles checking the validity of the arguments and what shall happen if the flag is present or not.

More specifically, here is my `gulpfile.js`:

```js
'use strict';

var argv = require('yargs').options({
    'config': {
        alias: 'c',
        demandOption: true,
        default: 'default',
        describe: 'Choose a configuration file name',
        type: 'string'
      },
    'host': {
        alias: 'h',
        demandOption: false,
        default: '',
        describe: 'Replace the host starting with http://',
        type: 'string'
    }
}).argv;

gulp.task('config', function(){

// If argument -c is passed copy config file in path 
// configs/Config_{{argv.c}}.js into Config.js
    gulp.src('./app/jsx/constants/Config_' + argv.c + '.js')
      .pipe(rename({ basename: 'Config'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/jsx/constants'))
})
```

If I `gulp config -c something`, everything works as expected.

What I would like to have is : having the CLI asking for a config argument if not provided in the command.

Has anyone had experience with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a little while to figure out that commenting out your `default` options within the `config` object makes it work.

It does make sense that if the `demandOption` is set to `true` that there should be **no default**! The documentation however doesn't appear to say anything about it (and it just fails silently), see [valid options keys](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/HEAD/docs/api.md#optionskey-opt).

Consistent with this theory is that your second not-required option, '`host`' works fine with even an undefined or null `default: ""`.